# Is there a simple way in Pyspark to find out number of promotions it took to convert someone into customer?

Tags: pyspark, group-by, pivot-table

I have a date-level promotion data frame that looks something like this:

| ID | Date | Promotions | Converted to customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2-Jan | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 10-Jan | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 14-Jan | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 10-Jan | 19 | 1 |
| 2 | 10-Jan | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | 10-Jan | 12 | 0 |

Now I want to see what were the number of promotions it took to convert someone into a customer
For eg., It took (2+3) promotions to convert ID 1 to the customer and (19) to convert ID 2 to the customer.

Eg.

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 19 |

I am unable to think of an idea to solve it. Can you please help me?

@Corralien and mozway have helped with the solution in Python. But I am unable to implement it in Pyspark because of the huge dataframe size (>1 TB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to generate a mask to hide the rows, then one [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) for the sum:

```
mask = (df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['Converted to customer']
          .apply(lambda s: s.eq(1).shift(fill_value=False).cummax())
       )

out = df[~mask].groupby('ID')['Promotions'].sum()
```

Output:

```
ID
1     5
2    19
Name: Promotions, dtype: int64
```

Alternative output:

```
df[~mask].groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(**{'Number': ('Promotions', 'sum')})
```

Output:

```
   ID  Number
0   1       5
1   2      19
```

If you potentially have groups without conversion to customer, you might want to also aggregate the "" column as indicator:

```
mask = (df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['Converted to customer']
          .apply(lambda s: s.eq(1).shift(fill_value=False).cummax())
       )

out = (df[~mask]
       .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
       .agg(**{'Number': ('Promotions', 'sum'),
               'Converted': ('Converted to customer', 'max')
              })
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID  Number  Converted
0   1       5          1
1   2      19          1
2   3      39          0
```

Alternative input:

```
   ID    Date  Promotions  Converted to customer
0   1   2-Jan           2                      0
1   1  10-Jan           3                      1
2   1  14-Jan           3                      0
3   2  10-Jan          19                      1
4   2  10-Jan           8                      0
5   2  10-Jan          12                      0
6   3  10-Jan          19                      0 # this group has
7   3  10-Jan           8                      0 # no conversion
8   3  10-Jan          12                      0 # to customer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mozway
Is there a way to do this in the Pyspark data frame? I have this huge data frame (>1TB) which I am unable to convert in Pandas Dataframe

Comment: @Mufeez probably, but you should [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the appropriate tags, this one was tagged pandas.

Comment: That will be helpful. THanks mozway

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
prom = (df.groupby('ID')['Promotions'].cumsum()
          .where(df['Converted to customer'].eq(1))
          .dropna().astype(int))

out = df.loc[prom.index, ['ID', 'Date']].assign(Promotion=prom)
print(out)

# Output
   ID     Date  Promotion
1   1  10-Jan           5
3   2  10-Jan          19
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the Pyspark data frame? I have this huge data frame (>1TB) which I am unable to convert in Pandas Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

you want to compute something by ID, so a groupby ID seems appropriate, e.g.

```
data.groupby("ID").apply(fct)
```

Now write a separate function agg_fct which computes the result for a
dataframe consisting of only one ID
Assuming data are ordered by Date, I guess that

```
def agg_fct(df):
   index_of_conv = df["Converted to customer"].argmax()
   return df.iloc[0:index_of_conv,df.columns.get_loc("Promotions")].sum()
```

would be fine. You might want to make some adjustments in case of a customer who has never been converted.